Running anchor build doesnt give any errors
Hello i am quite new to solana development and i am currently following the Solana Bootcamp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amAq-WHAFs8&t=5800s
In the solana bootcamp the nightly compiler successfully identifies errors when running anchor build.
However when i compile with the same command it compiles successfully everytime and gives no errors (even though there clearly are errors).
I use VSCode on WSL,
I run anchor cli 0.30.1
AVM 0.30.1
rustc 1.83.0 (90b35a623 2024-11-26)
rustup 1.27.1 (54dd3d00f 2024-04-24)
solana-cli 2.0.17 via Agave

Could you share the error or describe what's happening with the error?

Thats just it @Jimii, i run anchor build and it compiles with no errors, even though there is supossed to be errors.

What errors are supposed to be there. Can you share an explanation please.
